# Angular Pipe titlecase Invalid Pipe Error

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I want to apply titlecase pipe with alvis operator and it is not working as expected. While 'number' pipe is working as expected with alvis operator and TitleCasePipe().transform() is also working on the same value.

Option 1: `<p>Chain: {{information?.chains | titlecase}}</p>`

Throws Below Error:

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'bitcoin' for pipe 'TitleCasePipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:3953)
    at TitleCasePipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.TitleCasePipe.transform (common.js:4655)
    at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (core.js:9731)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10303)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10261)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:10894)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:10880)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (UserMenuComponent.html:8)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:10872)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10248)
```

Option 2: `<p>Chain: {{'bitcoin' | titlecase}}</p>`
Transforms the string value to 'Bitcoin', as expected.

Option 3: `console.log(new TitleCasePipe().transform(this.information.chain));`
Transforms the variable value 'bitcoin' to 'Bitcoin', as expected.

Option 4: `<p>Balance: {{information?.balance | number}}</p>`
Transforms the variable value 15603911 into 15,603,911, as expected.

How can i use titlecase pipe in html view with async data values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about trying?

```
<p>Chain: {{ (information?.chains || '') | titlecase}}</p>
```

Comment: Adding OR condition helped but my real issue was related to data type. chains was defined as string[] not string. Somehow, it was reading the first value from the array but it was unable to apply pipe on array :). Modified the code as '{{(undefined === information?.chains) ? '' : (information?.chains[0] | titlecase)}}'. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

To use [`TitleCasePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe), or any other pipe that expects a sync value, with async data, unwrap the resolved/emitted data with [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) (works with both `Promise` and `Observable`):

```html
<p>Balance: {{bitcoin$ | async | titlecase}}</p>
```

Comment: But i am already reading the value into object with subscription in my ts file:  import { GetInfo } from '../../../shared/models/getInfo';
  public information: GetInfo = {};

  this.appService.informationUpdated
    .takeUntil(this.infoSub)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.information = data;
    });

Comment: Then, I believe that only option left to transform is to do it into ts file itself. I am unable to understand the reason for 'number' pipe to work but 'titlecase' not.

Comment: I wish I could help you further, but your question does not show anything to reproduce your error. Please show `UserMenuComponent.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Titlecase pipe requires the CommonModule from @angular/common to be included. Could you please check if you have added that module?